# What is the purpose of safety control in older water baths?

Tags: heater

One like this:
[image]

> Most water baths have a second control called the safety. This control
> is set at the maximum tem- perature the water bath should attain. It
> is usually set just above the temperature control. Often an indicator
> light is associated with the safety control. If the water bath reaches
> the temperature that the safety control is set at, the light will go
> on. It will be impossible for the water bath to heat higher than the
> safety setting even when the temperature setting is higher.
> **BIOCHEMISTRY LABORATORY MANUAL: FOR MBBS, BDS, BHMS, BAMS, BUMS, BNYS AND DMLT STUDENTS**

How I read this is that setting the **temperature control** to a certain value will result in a certain **volume** of water reaching a certain corresponding **temperature** after some **time**. But because water evaporates even with the lid on, the volume of water will decrease the value of the temperature control will result in a higher temperature of the water.

If my reading is correct and the safety control solves this problem, how does it work?

Comment: Voting to reopen. This is not a question on the **use** of a product. The question is in the last sentence, "**... how does it work?**"

Answer (score 5):

It's common to have a temperature controller and a limit controller. They both operate on temperature. Typically you'd want to have both as independent as possible (separate devices, operating from separate sensors and with separate actuators such as relays). That's for redundancy.

In the case of a failure in the primary controller system (a bad sensor, a shorted triac or SCR, a sticky relay, or a controller failure) the limit controller will prevent the system from going too far out of control. The purpose is sometimes to protect whatever is in the controlled system (maybe it's an incubator or has a load of $50,000 worth of product) and sometimes also to prevent damage to the system itself, or to prevent the system from damaging other things (such as causing a fire). Sometimes the limit controller is less accessible to the user, helping to prevent user error. There's even an insurance approval scheme for such safety limit controllers.

Here is an excerpt from a [manual](https://%20https://www.seas.upenn.edu/%7Ebelab/equipment/equipment_links/Fisher_Water_Bath_Manual.pdf) for a similar product from the same supplier (emphasis added):

> These baths are microprocessor controlled for precise temperatures and
> reliable, trouble-free operation. Dual thermostats — one controlling
> the set point temperature and the other operating as a safety —
> **virtually eliminate the possibility of overheating**. Although not
> designed to operate dry, the bath will not be damaged if it is allowed
> to run dry.

Comment: Basically, why would someone would to turn the safety controller off so that they make it as a separate controller?

Comment: @FreezingSoul I don't understand your question, could you rephrase it please?

Comment: Basically, why would someone want to turn the safety controller off so that they make it as a separate controller? 

i meant to say "want" not would,,,, please check my comment @Transistor.

Comment: Ah, okay. Transistor probably has it. There's no good reason that I can think of other than to keep the two similar (and I suppose it would allow operation should the 'safety' controller fail). Lab equipment tends to place a higher level of trust in the user judgment than many other types of equipment. For example, Foodservice equipment is at the opposite end of the spectrum - - designed with the expectation that at least some of potential users should be limited in what they can do.  In this case the user can crank the control all the way up, which is equivalent to turning it off anyway.

Comment: For a skilled user, turning it off can be considered a convenience feature. Should the user judge that nothing much terrible would happen should a relatively unlikely overheating event occur, then there's a lot less reason to be fiddling about with two knobs keeping one just above the other, when adjusting one will do.

Answer (score 3):

From the comments to @Spehro's answer:

> Basically, why would someone would to turn the safety controller off so that they make it as a separate controller?

It looks like they've used the same model of thermostat for the control and the safety. Since the temperature control thermostat has a built-in on/off switch the safety controller gets one too. The advantage is standardisation of parts and reduction of bill of materials parts count.

> How I read this is that setting the temperature control to a certain value will result in a certain volume of water reaching a certain corresponding temperature after some time.

The temperature reached is independent of the volume. The time taken to reach that temperature will be proportional to the volume.

> But because water evaporates even with the lid on, the volume of water will decrease the value of the temperature control will result in a higher temperature of the water.

No. The contacts of the thermostat will open when the setpoint is reached, cutting off power and preventing further temperature rise.

There may be some problems if the tank runs dry - depending how the probe is mounted and how far it is from the heat source.

I suspect that the thermostat used is similar to an [oven thermostat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TcjHJZZgvuI).

---

From the comments:

> "Both thermostats are likely placed in the vicinity of the heater element."

I would disagree.

The thermostat should be placed in good contact with the water and not the heater. We don't care what the heater temperature is.

The thermostat is controlling the temperature of the **water**, not that of the element which needs to be much hotter than the water if heat is to flow from the heater to the water. If, say, trying to heat water to 50°C I would expect the heater element to be operating at > 200°C. The element will have some electrical insulation and a metal sheath (a bit like a kettle element does) and may be submerged in the water or fastened in good thermal contact to the underside of the metal tank. If there's water in the tank then there will be a temperature gradient. For example, the element wire might be at 200°C, the element sheath's temperature rise will be limited by the temperature of the metal tank which will be cooled by the water. So you might measure 60 - 80°C on the part of the element sheath in contact with the tank while the water approaches 50°C.

> The thermostat modulates the heater element temperature, not the water, right?

No. It modulates the element **power** going from fully-on to fully-off when the temperature reaches the set point. It's like driving with foot-to-the-floor until you reach the desired speed, take the foot off the accelerator until the speed drops below the target and then foot to the floor again. Thermostats are not subtle but usually they are set up to work reasonably well with systems with a slow response time.

Some numbers to remember: If you heat 1 L of water with a 1 kW element the temperature will rise 1°C every 4.2 s.

Comment: want*

          Wait does this mean that they want the safety controller to be completely independent of the temperature controller, from the start point (adjustment switch) to the end?

So basically this is a shadow temperature controller and my hypothesis is wrong and if the water volume decreases at any point, its temperature will raise?

Comment: I meant to ask in other words, does the thermostat care about the water temperature or just the heating element's?

Comment: See the update.

Comment: See glen_geek reply, "Both thermostats are likely placed in the vicinity of the heater element." The thermostat modulates the heater element temperature, not the water, right?

Comment: @FreezingSoul, see the update.

Answer (score 3):

Generic information from [a Fisher manual](https://assets.thermofisher.com/TFS-Assets/LED/manuals/D01203%7E.pdf) that applies to both 120V/220V versions:
[image: schematic fraction]

Two separate thermostats are wired in series to interrupt heater current. Either can stop heater. But only the thermostat set to a lower temperature *controls heater current*.
Each thermostats appear to mimic single-pole, single-throw switch (SPST). Its two states are open/close. An extra terminal drives a lamp.
The **high temperature limit pilot light** only lights up when its associated thermostat S3 is controlling temperature, and the normal **temperature control thermostat** S2 is *not* controlling temperature. These two thermostats appear to be identical.

Both thermostats are likely placed in the vicinity of the heater element. This is classed "Bang-bang" control system, like a refrigerator or home furnace. Crude. Fisher also makes more sophisticated temperature-control systems that use an electronic proportional-control, with RTD temperature sensor. It is unclear without a model number which type you have. (I suspect it is the crude bang-bang type).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a $500 water bath may be heating $10k worth of product that gets spoiled if it overheats. It sure wouldn't be nice if the failure of a single thermostat in a $500 piece of equipment lost the customer $10k.

Thermostats have a switch, whether mechanical or electrical, that can fail closed. It's a common failure mode. So that will lead to overheating, possibly a fire, financial losses either way, and so on.

By having two independent thermostats, the chances of both failing at the same time are vastly lower than the chances of just one failing. One thermostat is designated to be "safety" thermostat so that it doesn't "fight" with the primary thermostat.

In ultra-high-reliability water baths and similar equipment, where say $1M of product may get spoiled, there are independent power sources, and controls are designed using the same design principles as fly-by-wire controls in aircraft. Redundancies in both controls and sensors, voting, design diversity for backup controls, highly formalized engineering and manufacturing process, and so on.